# Android: DEFAULT activity showing up instead of LAUNCHER

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making a simple Android Application, which consists of only two activities, .Password and .Adder

```
<activity
        android:name=".Adder"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_adder" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Password"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_adder" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PASSWORD" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**The .Password activity is set as the LAUNCHER but when I run it, the .Adder Activity shows us instead.**

I have the .xml and .java file for both the activity properly connected by setContentView() and Eclipse is not reporting any kind of error in any file at all.

The Password Activity checks for the correct password and switches control to the Adder Activity:

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.example.pointsadder.MAIN");
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Password"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_adder" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PASSWORD" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

to this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Password"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_adder" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And modify this as shown:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Adder"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_adder" >
</activity>
```

Refer to this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#iconlabel for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You don t have to write intent filter to each activity. Correct xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Adder"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_adder" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Password"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_adder" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: +1. I had missed the modifications on the `.Adder` entry. ;-)